# Prometheus mysql-exporter

Tags: mysql, mariadb, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm trying to use Prometheus to get data from MariaDB. Userstat table in particular.

I've got three machines. On the first one, I have installed the MariaDB database, on the second one I have Prometheus and the third one has Grafana on it.

I set user state feature on MariaDB `SET GLOBAL userstat=1;`
and created mysql_exporter user

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'exporter'@'444.333.22.111' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'exporter'@'444.333.22.111';
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Next I installed Prometheus and mysql exporter on the second machine. I got the Prometheus from repositories and mysql_exporter as well.

Path to my exporter is:`/etc/default/prometheus-mysqld-exporter` and looks like:

```
# By default the connection string will be read from
# $HOME/my.cnf or -config.my-cnf.
# To set a connection string from the environment instead, uncomment the
# following line.

 export DATA_SOURCE_NAME="exporter:password@(444.333.22.111:3306)/mysql"
# Set the command-line arguments to pass to the exporter.
# ARGS='-config.my-cnf /etc/mysql/debian.cnf'

    -collect.auto_increment.columns
    -collect.binlog_size
    -collect.info_schema.userstats
    -config.my-cnf string
    -web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9104
```

Prometheus.yml:

```
# Sample config for Prometheus.

global:
  scrape_interval:     1s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
      monitor: 'example'

# Load and evaluate rules in this file every 'evaluation_interval' seconds.
rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s
    scrape_timeout: 5s

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
            - targets: ['localhost:9090', 'localhost:9104']

  - job_name: node
    # If prometheus-node-exporter is installed, grab stats about the local
    # machine by default.
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
```

Unfortunately it does not do what I want and keep monitoring the machine I have Prometheus installed on. Any ideas where could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if it's required - but from my experience you generally want to install the exporters on the machines where the services are running - i.e. install mysqld-exporter on the MariaDB server.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I was thinking an exporter can scrap database data from remote server. Do they have any documentation where could I find some hints on that topic?

Comment: It may be possible to install mysqld-exporter on a different server then MariaDB - but I've never seen an example of someone doing so. Perhaps try installing mysqld-exporter locally on MariaDB server and if the issue persists then you can continue troubleshooting from there.

Comment: Note that you should put the mysql exporter on its own job. job label is often use to identify the realm of metrics. I don't know what you expect but there is only one static configuration for your node exporter. There are lot of moving part in your description that don't add up. It is confusing. What do you mean by 'keep monitoring the machine I have Prometheus installed on' ?

Comment: My question basically is if I can remotely scrape data via prometheus mysql exporter? I have two machines, on the first one I have Prometheus and mysql exporter and on the second one I have MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to understand this first, **Exporter** needs to monitor metrics from **remote server**, therefore configuration of exporter should be correct as it is trying to request to the IP of **MariaDB** server i.e. `444.333.22.111` (remote server IP).

**MariaDB** server should whitelist the IP of **Exporter** server in order to allow any request from there.

**Solution:**
When you are creating user in **MariaDB** which in your case is `'exporter'@'444.333.22.111'`, therefore this means you are whitelisting `444.333.22.111` for user `exporter`.

But rather you should whitelist IP of the server, where `prometheus-mysqld-exporter` is setup. But in your case it's a different server. So it should be something like this

> MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER '**exporter**'@'**IP of exporter server**' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO '**exporter**'@'**IP of exporter server**';
> MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Try this and let me know in case you get any error and at the same time try looking at `prometheus-mysqld-exporter` logs.